# Not able to generate querydsl Q classes

Tags: mongodb, maven-plugin, spring-data, querydsl, spring-data-mongodb

I believe this question has been asked here for a while but there wasn't any accepted response. I've actually tried various tutorials but not getting them. I have a `multi modules` `maven` project. SO i have `dependency-management` and `plugin-management` in the parent project. the poms look like below:

```
<!--parent ${querydsl.version} = 2.3.2-->
 <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <!--                        <fork>true</fork>
                    -->                        
                    <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
                    <maxmem>512m</maxmem>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<dependencyManagment>
    <dependencies>
     <!-- Querydsl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End Querydsl -->
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagment>
```

I have in the db mobule both jpa and mongo, both in separate packages.But i only wish to use `query dsl` for mongodb. the db module pom looks like below:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${generatedSources}</outputDirectory>
                                 <processor>com.mysema.query.mongodb.morphia.MorphiaAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Querydsl -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Querydsl -->
</dependencies>
```

I'm using `spring data framework 3.1` with its `@Document` annotation on the mongo entities. I also use `MongoRepository` so am wondering if i should so something else before getting the classes Geneated.

thanks for reading

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`com.mysema.query.mongodb.morphia.MorphiaAnnotationProcessor` is meant to be used with [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/) annotated classes. For `@Document` annotated classes use `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt response. i've corrected the part you pointed but now having an error.please check: http://pastie.org/5403583

Comment: upgrade fixed the issue but i run into another issue which is not really `querydsl` concern but spring-data.https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-504?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel any work around to suggest to me?

Comment: Which versions of the Spring Data modules do you use? The only reason the ticket is still open is that I wanted to gather feedback on whether this is still an issue. Given there has not been any since August, this should be fixed with 1.1.0.RELEASE. 1.1.1.RELEASE is the latest bugfix release out there.

Comment: Hi @OliverGierke versions are `spring-data-mongo : 1.0.0.RELEASE`
`spring-data-commons-core : 1.2.1.RELEASE`
`spring-data-jpa : 1.1.0.M1` , `commons-collections: 3.2.1` ,`com.mysema.querydsl: 2.9.0` thanks

Comment: Please use the lates versions: SD MongoDB 1.1.1.RELEASE, SD JPA 1.2.0.RELEASE both based on SD Commons 1.4.0.RELEASE…

Comment: Any chance you show the repository interfaces? Something seems to break when trying to discover domain types.

Comment: Hi @OliverGierke, i've created a new post about the subject. Please let's continue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508250/issues-upgrading-from-spring-data-mongo thanks

Comment: For Spring boot , if you miss @Document, classes will not be generated!!

Comment: @Jayasagar I had the same problem with Spring-boot and  Q class do not created. I think your point is my key! where had to ad at"Document" ? at the entity top?

Comment: Hi.
I am using com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Entity to annotate my class and still it is not processed as Q class.
Thank you.